# Group correspoding key and values

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a use case to write a map reducing code where I have to group the values corresponding to the same queue:

*Input:*

```
A,B  
A,C  
B,A  
B,D
```

*Output:*

```
A {B,C}  
B {A,D}
```

I have written this code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class GroupKeyValues {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context con)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Text myKey = new Text();
            Text myVal = new Text();
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                String thisH = st.nextToken();
                String[] splitData = thisH.split(",");
                myKey.set(splitData[0]);
                myVal.set(splitData[1]);
            }
            con.write(myKey, myVal);

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "GroupKeyValues");

        job.setJarByClass(GroupKeyValues.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The import for string tokenizer is already present please check the code again.

Comment: This is just a statement, please update your post to include the exact question that you want to ask.-- Also explain what the status is of the code that you have provided.

Comment: The aim is to achive or group values corresponding to the keys, in here the first column acts as keys, it is as if am grouping in column 1.

Comment: U can see my question where i have mentioned sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing reducer that will aggregate values into a single "row" value. For example, you can use ArrayWritable like this:

```java
public static class AggregatingReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, ArrayWritable> {
  private ArrayWritable result = new ArrayWritable(Text.class);
    
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<Text> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Text value : values) {
      list.add(value);
    }
    result.set(list.toArray(new Text[list.size()]));
    context.write(key, result);
  }
}
```

In the job setup, make sure to add this:

```java
job.setReducerClass(AggregatingReducer.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(ArrayWritable.class);  //instead of Text.class
```

Alternatively (depending on what you need) you can concatenate reducer values into StringBuilder and emit Text instead of accumulating it into and emitting it as ArrayWritable.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the example of StringBuilder use with comma delimiter:

```java
public static class AggregatingReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
  private Text result = new Text();
    
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Text value : values) {
      if (sb.length() != 0) {
        sb.append(',');
      }
      sb.append(value);
    }
    result.set(sb.toString());
    context.write(key, result);
  }
}
```

In the driver value type needs to be changed back to Text:

```java
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Comment: I tried the above reducer code but i am getting error during run time stating Expecting arrayeritable rather getting text kind of value.

Comment: Because mapper value is now different from a job output, you have to specify mapper value type explicitly: job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

Comment: I tried setting the MapOutputClass to Text, this time it ran but I could not get output as expected : Please find the below output that I got while running:  
  
  A org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable@1f08ed8  
  B org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable@1f08ed8  
  D org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable@1f08ed8  
  L org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable@1f08ed8

Comment: Do you really need text output? You can use sequence file binary output format, to pass it to another mapper and so on.

Comment: I need a text output I am expecting an output which is of type GROUP in PIG if do it 1st column.

Comment: In that case it would be better to use alternative I mentioned. Accumulate in string builder and emit output value as Text.

Comment: Could you please help me out using String builder functionality. I was unable to get that.

Comment: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: the string builder function got my result, rhank you.

Comment: Do you consider the answer accepted? If so please mark it so or let me know if you have any issues remaining. Thanks!

Comment: I have already marked it, as I donot have 15 grade points , it is not visible, but the ack is done and it will reflect ur badge points.

Answer (score 0):

Are you consider using Apache Spark to solve the issue?
The code might look like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","A"),("B","D")))
val dfAgg = df.groupBy("_1").agg(collect_list("_2"))
dfAgg.show()
```